# How do I use the last value in an array as a path for .child() when retrieving a snapshot?

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, snapshot

I'm new to Firebase and have a function that writes all of my event ID's to an array. I want to use the last value in that array (the last event ID) to lookup the children of that specific eventID.

I know how to get the last item in the array but how do I put that into my .child() path?

I tried the code below, but it doesn't seem to work. I'm guessing that because .child("(lastEvent)") isn't a valid path.

```
let lastEvent = eventIDArray.last
refHandle = ref.child("Bouts").child("\(lastEvent)")
```

How do I plug the lastEvent value in as my path? Or is that even possible? Again, total newbie- alternatives welcome.

Answer (score 0):

## Sorting and filtering data

you can use sorting and filtering function to get the item.
To get the last item you can write the query like this.**

```
let recentBoutsQuery = (ref?.child("Bouts").queryLimited(toLast: 1))!
```

This will return 1 entry from last of your database which the last entry.

You can learn more from the firebase documentation. [Work with Lists of Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data)

Comment: Thanks Ashutosh, how do I take a snapshot of that value, do I add the .observe onto the end of it? I need to grab the children of that node.

Comment: Yes,you can loop the result. since it has only one item loop will run only once.
recentBoutsQuery.observe(.value) { snapshot in
  for child in snapshot.children {
   
  }
}